# Is it possible to manipulate the layout in react and save it?

Tags: reactjs, layout

I want to make a layout with a flexible partitioning in ReactJS.
Elements should change their size by dragging (or equal operation).

When working with fat clients (desktop applications), it is possible to manipulate the layout of the application. E.g. is adjusting the size of a section by pushing the the left mouse button at the border of the section and keep it hold. Moving to the left or right direction will shrink or increase the size of the section. Another handy example is the cell in Excel. You can define it's size by manipulating the row or column size (thus affecting the positioning on any following columns/size).

1. Is this possible (in ReactJS)?
2. Is this a ReactJS problem? (or simply affects only CSS or any other technology?)
3. Let's say you adjusted
           the size elements for yourself. Is it possible to save the
           customization, so that I as user don't have to adjust it again?

Answer (score 0):

As I found out, it isn't a specific reactjs problem. It's about JS in general.

If you want to store a customized layout with its values, you should use 
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage